# Function from external js

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I want to move this part of my code to a external js file

```
$(function hotels() {
var availableTags = [
"Akwa Guesthouse",
"Al-Hut Bungalow",
"Ali Beach Resort",
"Aloha Resort",
"Al´s Resort",
"Amadeus Bungalow",
];
$( "#hotels" ).autocomplete({
source: availableTags
});
```

and then get it back into my php file to use for an input field like this.

```
<input id="hotels" class="eingabe required" />
```

it works if I add the script to the php file but I'm struggling to have it called from an external file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just save your javascript file, for example `script.js`, then called in your php file using script tags, like this `<script type="text/javascript" src="script.js"></script>`.

Example:

```
<?php
...your php code goes here...
?>

<html>
    <head>
        <!-- Your external javascript here -->
        <script type="text/javacript" src="script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
    </body>
</html>
```